# How to stop WhatsApp from deleting media from gallery when the sender deletes that message?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, media-files

When someone sends me media (photo/video) on WhatsApp, I can download it, and it gets saved to my phone's internal storage, in a gallery album created by WhatsApp called "WhatsApp Images".

If the person who sent the media then deletes that message from the chat, the media file is then deleted from my phone's internal storage too, although I have already downloaded it. However, if I move the media file out of the "WhatsApp Images" gallery album before the message is deleted, then the media is not deleted from my phone.

Is there any way to prevent WhatsApp from deleting media from the "WhatsApp Images" album after I have downloaded them, if the sender deletes the message?

Comment: You can't prevent this in official WhatsApp. Use some modded WhatsApp app. Or use `inotify` based commandline tools or an app to watch newly created files and then copy/move the images to some other directory before it's being deleted.

Comment: I think there are some apps that can automatic copy any new picture that comes in. You can also use a service like Google photos which is free (till the summer) and have it back up any new picture. This way, even if it's deleted, you'll still have it